# Intercept HttpClient with third party extensions using state

Tags: c#, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

Injecting state into your HttpRequest when using IHttpClientFactory is achievable by populating  `HttpRequestMessage.Properties` see [Using DelegatingHandler with custom data on HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66261647/using-delegatinghandler-with-custom-data-on-httpclient)

Now if I have third party extensions on HttpClient (such as IdentityModel), how would I intercept these http requests using custom state?

```cs
public async Task DoEnquiry(IHttpClientFactory factory)
{
    var id = Database.InsertEnquiry();
    var httpClient = factory.CreateClient();
    // GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync is a third party extension method on HttpClient
    // I therefore cannot inject or alter the request message to be handled by the InterceptorHandler
    var discovery = await httpClient.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync();
    // I want id to be associated with any request / response GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync is making
}
```

The only plausible solution I currently have is to override HttpClient.

```cs
public class InspectorHttpClient: HttpClient
{
    
    private readonly HttpClient _internal;
    private readonly int _id;

    public const string Key = "insepctor";

    public InspectorHttpClient(HttpClient @internal, int id)
    {
        _internal = @internal;
        _id = id;
    }
    
    public override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // attach data into HttpRequestMessage for the delegate handler
        request.Properties.Add(Key, _id);
        return _internal.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }

    // override all methods forwarding to _internal
}
```

A then I'm able to intercept these requests.

```cs
public async Task DoEnquiry(IHttpClientFactory factory)
{
    var id = Database.InsertEnquiry();
    var httpClient = new InspectorHttpClient(factory.CreateClient(), id);
    var discovery = await httpClient.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync();
}
```

Is that a plausible solution? Something tell me now not to override HttpClient. Quoting from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-5.0

> The HttpClient also acts as a base class for more specific HTTP clients. An example would be a FacebookHttpClient providing additional methods specific to a Facebook web service (a GetFriends method, for instance). Derived classes should not override the virtual methods on the class. Instead, use a constructor overload that accepts HttpMessageHandler to configure any pre- or post-request processing instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I almost included this in [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66262600/263693) as an alternative solution, but I figured it was too long already. :)

The technique is practically the same, but instead of `HttpRequestMessage.Properties`, use `AsyncLocal<T>`. "Async local" is kind of like thread-local storage but for a specific asynchronous code block.

There are a few caveats to using `AsyncLocal<T>` that aren't particularly well-documented:

1. Use an immutable nullable type for `T`.
2. When setting the async local value, return an `IDisposable` that resets it.

   - If you don't do this, then only set the async local value from an `async` method.

You don't *have* to follow these guidelines, but they will make your life much easier.

With that out of the way, the solution is similar to the last one, except it just uses `AsyncLocal<T>` instead. Starting with the helper methods:

```
public static class AmbientContext
{
  public static IDisposable SetId(int id)
  {
    var oldValue = AmbientId.Value;
    AmbientId.Value = id;
    // The following line uses Nito.Disposables; feel free to write your own.
    return Disposable.Create(() => AmbientId.Value = oldValue);
  }

  public static int? TryGetId() => AmbientId.Value;

  private static readonly AsyncLocal<int?> AmbientId = new AsyncLocal<int?>();
}
```

Then the calling code is updated to set the ambient value:

```
public async Task DoEnquiry(IHttpClientFactory factory)
{
  var id = Database.InsertEnquiry();
  using (AmbientContext.SetId(id))
  {
    var httpClient = factory.CreateClient();
    var discovery = await httpClient.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync();
  }
}
```

Note that there is an explicit *scope* for that ambient id value. Any code within that scope can get the id by calling `AmbientContext.TryGetId`. Using this pattern ensures that this is true for *any* code: synchronous, `async`, `ConfigureAwait(false)`, whatever - all code within that scope can get the id value. Including your custom handler:

```
public class HttpClientInterceptor : DelegatingHandler
{
  protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  {
    var id = AmbientContext.TryGetId();
    if (id == null)
      throw new InvalidOperationException("The caller must set an ambient id.");

    // associate the id with this request
    Database.InsertEnquiry(id.Value, request);
    return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
  }
}
```

Followup readings:

- [Blog post on "async local"](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/implicit-async-context-asynclocal.html) - written before `AsyncLocal<T>` existed, but has details on how it works. This answers the questions "why should `T` be immutable?" and "if I don't use `IDisposable`, why do I have to set the value from an `async` method?".

Comment: Brilliant. Would you consider all of this (IHttpClientFactory, Custom DelgatingHandlers, and local storage) better as opposed to the old fashion `WebRequest.Create(uri)` with own instantiation, own handlers etc.?

Comment: @WillemBijker: Figuring out all the pieces can be difficult, but once you have all the pieces together, I think it's a cleaner API.